# How do I filter an Array of photo names?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

[image]I have an Array of image names that include a UUID.

images

```
[
 "auditid_626_UUID_666666_time__1582577405550.jpg",
 "auditid_626_UUID_999999_time__1582577405554.jpg",
 "auditid_626_UUID_999999_time__1582577405557.jpg"
]
```

I am displaying them in a html page with this

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let img of images; index as pos" class="ion-text-wrap">
    <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
      <ion-img [src]="img.path"></ion-img>
    </ion-thumbnail>

    <ion-textarea auto-grow="true" >{{ img.name }}</ion-textarea>
    <ion-button slot="end" fill="clear" (click)="startUpload(img)">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" src="assets/upload.svg"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    <ion-button slot="end" fill="clear" (click)="deleteImage(img, pos)">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The method I am using to call this array is

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.testID = "666666";
}

loadStoredImages() {
  this.storage.get(this.STORAGE_KEY).then(images => {
    if (images) {
      let arr = JSON.parse(images);
      this.images = [];  // filter here  .filter((images: any[]) => { return images.includes(this.testID) } );
      for (let img of arr) {
        let filePath = this.file.dataDirectory + img;
        let resPath = this.pathForImage(filePath);
        this.images.push({ name: img, path: resPath, filePath: filePath });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is filter the array to only include the UUID's that contain `this.testID = "666666";` I started working on my filter at `this.images = [];` I am unsure how the filter would be applied to `this.images = [];` Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

image from xcode log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list must be like this :

```
let list = [
 "auditid_626_UUID_666666_time__1582577405550.jpg",
 "auditid_626_UUID_999999_time__1582577405554.jpg",
 "auditid_626_UUID_999999_time__1582577405557.jpg"
];
```

Then try this :

```
loadStoredImages() {
  this.storage.get(this.STORAGE_KEY).then(images => {
    if (images) {
      let arr = JSON.parse(images);
      this.images = this.images.filter(a => a.includes("UUID_" + this.testID));
      for (let img of arr) {
        let filePath = this.file.dataDirectory + img;
        let resPath = this.pathForImage(filePath);
        this.images.push({ name: img, path: resPath, filePath: filePath });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Example :

```js
let list = ["auditid_626_UUID_666666_time__1582577405550.jpg",
 "auditid_626_UUID_999999_time__1582577405554.jpg",
 "auditid_626_UUID_999999_time__1582577405557.jpg"
];
const result = list.filter(a => a.includes("UUID_666666"));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I cannot edit my list to add names . I have attached a screenshot from xcode.  This is the tutorial I have been using.   https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-image-upload-storage/

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your last update

Answer (score 2):

```
let filtered = arr.filter(x => x.name.includes('UUID_' + this.testID));
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrkfd)

Note structure of array - objects added like

```
{name: 'auditid_626_UUID_666666_time__1582577405550.jpg'}
```

Comment: Edited to prefix with 'UUID_' as per @Oussail answer. To remove any false positives.

Answer (score 0):

Using Oussails answer I the used the following code.  Note I had to move the filter to varible arr and not this.images

```
loadStoredImages() {
  this.storage.get(this.STORAGE_KEY).then(images => {
    if (images) {
      let arr = JSON.parse(images);
      this.images = [];
      arr  = arr.filter(a => a.includes("UUID_" + this.testID));
      for (let img of arr) {
        let filePath = this.file.dataDirectory + img;
        let resPath = this.pathForImage(filePath);
        this.images.push({ name: img, path: resPath, filePath: filePath });
      }
    }
  });
}
```